# Configure swagger yaml so that arrays can be generated into List or Set

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen

Given some swagger schema types, e.g.:

```
arrayOfString:
  type: array
    items:
      type: string
```

While using `io.swagger.codegen.v3` to generate Java classes, is there some configuration you can add (per schema type, not globally set) to tell whether you want it to generate `List` or `Set` for arrays?

Comment: Why do you want `Set` instead of `List`? `List` is generally easier to work with if you don't need the uniqueness guarantee.

Comment: Then you have a mismatch between your internal representation and your schema regarding both uniqueness and ordering.

Comment: The indentation in your example is wrong - `items` must be on the same level as `type: array`. Is this how your YAML is actually indented, or copy-paste issues?